# What is the basis of the vector space of real numbers over rational numbers?

Tags: vector-spaces, real-numbers, hamel-basis

So the real numbers for a vector space over the rational numbers. The dimension is infinite. Is it countably infinite or uncountably infinite?

Comment: A basis exists because of the axiom of choice, but it cannot be explicitly exhibited. It's uncountable for cardinality reasons: since the rational are countable, if $B$ is an infinite linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$), the span of $B$ has cardinality $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It is going to have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, so uncountable.