# Does the set of Real numbers has basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that set of rational numbers as a module over $\mathbb  Z$ hasn't basis. What about ,$\left (\mathbb R, +  \right )$ has it basis? If no, how to proof that?

Comment: In the sense of a vector space? Then what is the scalar field?

Comment: Yes, $\{1\}$ is a basis of the $\Bbb R$-vector space $\Bbb R$. Over $\Bbb Q$, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515165/what-is-the-basis-of-the-vector-space-of-real-numbers-over-rational-numbers).

Comment: And $\{1\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb Q$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Are you asking if $\mathbb{R}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Dedekind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem?wprov=sfla1), if Choice holds then every subgroup of a free abelian group is free. If $\mathbb{R}$ were free, then $\mathbb{Q}$ would be too.